# vex confirm dialog, how can i manage the a href-event handling

Tags: jquery, dialog, confirm

I'm trying to use https://github.com/HubSpot/vex modal script for a confirm-dialog. If cancel is selected, the event of the href should cancel.

My a href:

```
<a href="goto.php" class="confirm" >confirm</a>
```

and my javascript:

```
$('a.confirm').click(function() {
                var page = $(this).attr('rel');
                vex.dialog.buttons.YES.text = 'Cancel';
                vex.dialog.buttons.NO.text = 'Go further';
                vex.dialog.confirm({
                        message: 'Are you sure to go?',
                        callback: function(value) {
                        if(value === false) {
                          //load the a href-site    
                        } else {
                          // cancel;
                          return false;
                        }
                        }
                    });
        });
```

Unfortunately the a href-site will just loaded after i click on the confirm-link. Do anybody can say me how a can change this event-handling?

thanks in advance.

best regards
thomas

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately now it exit the hole handling - even when i click ok. But on the ok-click it should work like a normal link. i tried to put return true - but this doesn't worked! thanks for your help.

Comment: if(value === false) { … this means, that everything is ok, now it should open the src-file of a href .. }

Comment: can you see it?: http://jsfiddle.net/stiller/LqP2K/   thanks in advance

Comment: And are you able to work with provided fiddle? I think that the fiddle is not finished with the code

Comment: sorry, now the fiddle should work.

Comment: This should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/adamschwartz/v44KH/